# C# Timer counter in xx.xx.xx format

Tags: c#, timer, formatting, int

I have a counter that counts up every 1 second and add 1 to an int.

**Question**
How can I format my string so the counter would look like this:

> 00:01:23

Instead of:

> 123

**Things I've tried**
Things I've tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            _Counter += 1;
            labelUpTime.Text = _Counter.ToString();
        }
```

My timer's interval is set to: 1000 (so it adds 1 every second).
I did read something about string.Format(""), but I don't know if it is applicable.
Thanks if you can guide me through this :D!

Comment: Turning 123 seconds into "1:23" is going to be difficult.  Consider "2:03".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a TimeSpan:

```
_Counter += 1;
labelUpTime.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Counter).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a `TimeSpan` (for that's what it is, a span of time), then format that:

```
labelUpTime.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_Counter).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a counter, and don't rely on the timer firing exactly every second. It won't. Do something like this.

```
class TimerTest
{
    private DateTime _start = DateTime.Now;
    private Timer _timer = new Timer(1000);

    public TimerTest()
    {
        // (DateTime.Now - _start) returns a TimeSpan object
        // Default TimeSpan.ToString() returns 00:00:00
        _timer.Elapsed = (o, e) => labelUpTime.Text = (DateTime.Now - _start).ToString();
    }
}
```

You can adjust the formatting with the [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan timer = new TimeSpan(0);
```

and on your interval:

```
timer += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use timespan. To add a second use

```
mytimespan.Add(new TimespanFromSeconds(1));
Console.WriteLine(mytimespan);    //Output in the form of xx:xx:xx
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan

Answer (score 0):

it worked well for me

```
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTimeFormatted
    {
        get
        {
            if (FinishedOn != null &&
                StartedAt != null)
            {
                TimeSpan durationCount = new TimeSpan();

                int hours = 0;
                int minutes = 0;
                int seconds = 0;

                var times = Segments.Select(c => c.ElapsedTimeFormatted).ToList();

                foreach (var time in times)
                {
                    TimeSpan timeParse = TimeSpan.Parse(time);

                    hours = hours + (int)timeParse.Hours;
                    minutes = minutes + (int)timeParse.Minutes;
                    seconds = seconds + (int)timeParse.Seconds;

                    durationCount = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
                }

                return durationCount;
            }

            return new TimeSpan();
        }
    }
```